# Append query string to all URLs with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

For testing purposes, I would like to append a query string (let's say testing=true) to any url requested from my website.

E.g. I want to change

- example.com
- example.com/product
- example.com/search?q=string

to

- example.com?**testing=true**
- example.com/product?**testing=true**
- example.com/search?q=string&**testing=true**

I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://example.com/$1?testing=true [L,R,NE]
```

but it breaks the site. Not an expert.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I should add I'm working with CodeIgniter (PHP) and my current .htaccess looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this new rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)testing=true(&|$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?testing=true [L,QSA,R]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|css)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it does nothing. Pages load with normal URLs, the query string is not appended.