# Add dynamic query vars to all urls with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to add a query parameter to the end of all URLs on a site but that value needs to be dynamic.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)testing=true(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?testing=true [L,QSA,R]
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297526/append-query-string-to-all-urls-with-htaccess) answer (code above) is very close to what I need, but I need 'true' to change based on the user provided value. An example would be various campaign ID's

http://domain.com/?campaign=32324

And when a user clicks on a link from this page, those links should append the ?campaign=32324

**http://domain.com/somepage/?campaign=43454**

Comment: It would be a time saver to post the relevant code from the answer you reference in your question.

Comment: @anubhava http://domain.com/?campaign=XXXX should redirect any link clicked on that page to have the same campaign id. eg: http://domain.com/somepage/ should redirect to http://domain.com/somepage/?campaign=XXXX if clicked on from the homepage.

Comment: Not clear. This is the page user is already on: `http://domain.com/somepage/?campaign=43454` Now clarify what it should be redirected to?

Comment: They should not be redirected anywhere while on that page. But if they click on a link while on that page, the next page they go to should also have the same ?campaign=XXX append to it. The QSA flag gets me pretty close to this, but where 'true' is, I need that to be the dynamic campaign id.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append a query string to a URL, I believe this is what you're looking for.

Of course your parameter and/or its value can be populated in any number of ways. It can be passed from a previous page and populated by `$_GET['something']` or provided by a DB query and populated from the results.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)$    your-page.php?your-parameter=$1    [NC,L] # Handle query string with no slash
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)/$    your-page.php?your-parameter=$1    [NC,L] # Handle query string with a slash
```

The [A-Za-z0-9_-] portion allows a parameter value to include upper & lower case letters, numbers, underscore and hyphen. If all you want are numbers (as in your examples) simply remove everything between the square brackets except 0-9 like so... [0-9]

Comment: @MikeSawicki - Do you need more help? If this answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).
Also see [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) and [Why is voting important?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).